# Eclipse default project problems

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm just now downloaded and installed Android SDK and SDK in my Ubuntu system and I've successfully linked them. I created a new Android Project but, on the default creation there is a class named `R` as shown in the image below and it is showing some error on it when I build the default project.

[image]

Comment: clean and rebuild your project its just a common issue.

Comment: @Shushant No, I can clean but on running it shows an error that "Your project has some error"...

Comment: please provide full error log

Comment: R cannot be resolved to a variable

Comment: It could sound stupid, but is R a class imported in the java file? Try to do Ctrl + Shift + O in the Java editor. If R exists in the Generated Java Files folder should fix your issue.

Comment: I've solved the issue - I've installed Java 32 bit libraries in my 64-bit PC and I cleaned and built again. Now it works.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Android Sdk Manager and install android-build-tools. after installation clean project, so it can generate the R.java in gen folder.